# Is it possible to make Netcat behave exactly like Telnet?

Tags: telnet, netcat

Is it possible to make Netcat behave exactly like Telnet?

The "-t" option doesn't seem to quite do it.

Comment: This would be a better question if you described the features that you want and don’t have. It might also help to specify what server/service you are connecting to. … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: Hi Scott. The question is totally clear. Anyone reading this site would understand the difference in protocols between netcat and telnet.

Comment: Heh, for anyone reading who does not, here's a great explanation of the protocols on this very site .. https://superuser.com/questions/1461609/what-is-the-difference-between-telnet-and-netcat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. While itay well be possible to get netcat to do what you want it to as if it were telnet, Telnet has a lot of archaic/arcane functionality built into it which is simply not present in netcat

Comment: Good to know.  I thought there might be an obscure option/combo that turns on telnet protocols.  Cheers