# Make Putty show raw bytes without encoding

Tags: putty

I have ESP8266 as WiFi node which I can connect to. There is byte stream from 24bit adc which I access with Putty on particular IP address on ESP. I want Putty session to print raw bytes, but it looks like, it will always display it is some encoding. The range of bytes values are from 0x00 to 0xff and every byte value may appear in output as adc have 24bit precision. It there some way to make Putty show raw bytes or use some 8bit encoding where there are no blank spaces, eg. for every byte value in range 0x00 to 0xff there is valid character which can be than converter to raw byte with some script?

Comment: @RomeoNinov [Telnet is not the right tool here either](https://superuser.com/a/1461622/432690).

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski, correct :) But i see putty have `RAW` mode which probably can be used. But again: how OP want to see 0x00 to 0x1f?

Comment: "… which can be than converter to raw byte with some script" – If you want raw bytes then there is no point in converting back and forth. E.g. in Linux `nc … | whatever` will pass received data to `whatever` you want. What is your OS? If you want to stick to PuTTY then maybe its `plink -raw` can be used; I'm not sure, I don't really know these tools. Anyway, do you want to actually *see* some representation of raw bytes? or store raw bytes? or pass raw bytes verbatim to another tool? Beware of [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310).

Comment: Sorry for late reply. @KamilMaciorowski exactly. I am sending bytes in range 0 to 255 and want to see them in Putty by their numerical values.

Comment: I thought you wanted to see what you are *receiving*, but now you're telling us you want to see what you are *sending*. This is getting even weirder. How do you send 0x00 or 0xff in PuTTY?

Comment: Sorry if I am not clear. I have esp which I connect to as wifi router. Then I open Putty on port and IP matching esp's. I am using Putty with raw connection type. After this, I am able to see data. The problem is, the data are represented as character (graphically) in Putty window. I want to see numerical values of these bytes. For example if I have number 123456 on adc, esp sends bytes [0, 241, 64]. I want see these numerical values in Putty.

Comment: I'm not convinced PuTTY is a right tool for this. In Linux, in Bash `nc address port | while …` should work, where the `while` loop is the one from [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/626655/108618). Use `%02x` instead of `%d` for hex.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Thanks for Your reply, it works.